# Web Components: How to listen to form input changes

Tags: javascript, event-handling, web-component, shadow-dom

I am working on a Web Component that should send data via a form to a server. In this example, I have the Object `Meal` and want to send a `name` to a server, coming from a form.

The HTML gets rendered by **handlers.js** like this: I am saving the value of the input field "name" for my component in the `mapDOM` method.

```
export default {
    render() {
        return `${this.html()}`;
    },

     mapDOM(scope) {
        return {
            name: scope.getElementById('name').value,
          }
    },
 
    html() {
        return `<form id="addEssenForm">
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="name">Name*</label>
                     <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text">
                   </div>
                   <button id="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Hinzufügen</button>
                </form>                
                `
    }
```

**meal-add.component.js**

```
export default class MealAddComponent extends HTMLElement {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = Template.render();
    this.dom = Template.mapDOM(this.shadowRoot);

    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('change', e => {
            // Now get the new values of the input field.
        }
    );
  }
```

Now I have no idea, how my component can get the changes which are made in the input. The eventlistener indeed is working, it triggers the method everytime I update the input field.

Answer (score 0):

The `attributeChangedCallback` does not trigger because you do not change the **attribute** `name` on the `<meal-add>` element (or whatever name you gave it)

I don't understand the need for a MutationObserver.
Attach an EventListener to the `input` and `button`, and you can fire a `submit` event in/to the host document. If you emit an Event from within shadowDOM remember to set `composed:true` so it escapes shadowDOM

also note:

```
 super();
 this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
 this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = Template.render();
```

can be written as:

```
 super()
   .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
   .innerHTML = Template.render();
```

Comment: I think you are right, leaving out the MutationObserver works. Now I am asking myself, how do I get the current value of my input field `name` from the Template? I would like to add the EventListener to the `essen-add.component.js` and not to the `template.js`

Comment: With tight coupling you call a setter on the other component to rertrieve the value (or a getAttribute if that is available) For loose coupled components it is best to do all communication with **custom** Events, that way it doesn't matter where components are in the DOM. Attach listeners on the first shared parent, or above.. all the way to ``document`` if you want. That is more boilerplate code, but flexible

Comment: Not your use case, but close enough, A form and a lookup field using Events: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/4fq7wnt9/